# Android Dev Help: Saving an image from Res/raw or Asset folder to the Sd card

Tags: android

I am trying to save an image (jpg or png) from the res/raw or assets folder to the SD card location (/sdcard/DCIM/).

I have been following a tutorial which can save an image from a URL to the SD card Root, but i have looked everywhere to be able to save from res/raw or asset folder instead, and to a differnet location onthe sd card /sdcard/DCIM/

Here is the code, can anyone show me how to do the above from this?

```
public class home extends Activity {
    private File file;
     private String imgNumber;
     private Button btnDownload;
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main); 
       btnDownload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);

      btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
       btnDownload.setText("Download is in Progress.");
      String savedFilePath=Download("http://www.domain.com/android1.png");
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Saved in  "+savedFilePath, 1000).show();
      if(savedFilePath!=null)
      {
        btnDownload.setText("Download Completed.");
      }
     }
    });

    } 
    public String Download(String Url)
    {
    String filepath=null;
    try {
    //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
    //this is the file to be downloaded
    URL url = new URL(Url);
    //create the new connection
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //set up some things on the connection
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    //and connect!
    urlConnection.connect();
    //set the path where we want to save the file
    //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
    //sd card.
    File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
    //which we want to save the file as.

    String filename= "download_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";   // you can download to any type of file ex:.jpeg (image) ,.txt(text file),.mp3 (audio file)
    Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
    file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
    if(file.createNewFile())
    {
    file.createNewFile();
    }

    //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

    //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    //this is the total size of the file
    int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
    //variable to store total downloaded bytes
    int downloadedSize = 0;

    //create a buffer...
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

    //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
    while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
    //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
    Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
    btnDownload.setText("download Status:"+downloadedSize+" / "+totalSize);
    }
    //close the output stream when done
    fileOutput.close();
    if(downloadedSize==totalSize) filepath=file.getPath();

    //catch some possible errors...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    filepath=null;

    btnDownload.setText("Internet Connection Failed.\n"+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("filepath:"," "+filepath) ; 
    return filepath;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested and working code:

In order to copy image from resources (image1.png) to the image file in the Pictures directory (image1.jpg) on SD card you can try the following approach (android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE needed for saving image on the SD card). ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE broadcast has been sent in order to pass new picture to the media scanner, so it would be visible in the Media Gallery ASAP.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View

public class MainScreen extends Activity 
{ 
    private Button btnDownload;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override     
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {         
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        setContentView(R.layout.main);     
        btnDownload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SaveButton1);

        btnDownload.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String newPicture = saveToSDCard(R.drawable.image1, "image1.jpg");
                    startMediaScanner(newPicture);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private String saveToSDCard(int resourceID, String finalName)
    {
        StringBuffer createdFile = new StringBuffer();

        Bitmap resourceImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), resourceID);       
        File externalStorageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), finalName);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        resourceImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        byte b[] = bytes.toByteArray(); 

        try 
        {
            externalStorageFile.createNewFile(); 
            OutputStream filoutputStream = new FileOutputStream(externalStorageFile); 
            filoutputStream.write(b); 
            filoutputStream.flush(); 
            filoutputStream.close();
            createdFile.append(externalStorageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

        return createdFile.toString();
    }

    private void startMediaScanner(String addedPicture)
    {
         sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+ addedPicture)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Zelimir, thanks you for this, i feel i'm almost there, i just have 1 error in eclipse, that is the DIRECTORY_PICTURES is in red, and the error box says "DIRECTORY_PICTURES cannot be resolved or is not a field"  How do i resolve this?

Comment: Hi, Have resolved the DIRECTORY_PICTURES issue, but how do i tell the system that a new file has been added, so that the user can view it straight away in their gallery of images, i believe its to do with the MediaScanner, how is this implemented in the code?  Thanks so much already.  Lucy

Comment: Yes, MediaScanner should be used for that. However, try firstly just to open Media Gallery and see if it is already there. Some phones (like Nexus one) do it at Media Gallery opening.

Comment: Hi, I have tried opening the gallery several times and it doesnt appear their at all, i have chaecked the sd card and it is present in the Pictures folder.  How would the MediaScanner fit in with the code your kindly posted. Thanks Lucy

Comment: Hi Zelimir, I dont think its made any difference as the gallery will still not show the image? also i dont even get the toast message! Hope you can help further, Thankyou, Lucy.

Comment: Tried it on my phone. Used ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + fileName);

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

int n = 0;
int o = 0;
while ((n = bis.read(buf, o, buf.length)) != 0) {
  bos.write(buf, 0, n);
}

bis.close();
bos.close();
```