# Android Help with Saving an image to Sd Card and SendBroadcast to MediaScanner

Tags: java, android, image, sd-card

I am having some trouble with saving an image from r.drawable.image1 to the phone's SD Card in a Pictures Folder, then sending a broadcast to the MediaScanner to refresh the folders so that the image appears in the gallery on the phone.

I beleive the solution is something to do with this

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

The problem now is the image does not save to sd and I do not know where to put the above code for the media scanner as the code below does nothing now after me fiddling with it for the last 3 days. Please Help...

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

public class MainScreen extends Activity 
{ 
    private Button btnDownload;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override     
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {         
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        setContentView(R.layout.main);     
        btnDownload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SaveButton1);

        btnDownload.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String newPicture = saveToSDCard(R.drawable.image1, "image1.jpg");
                    startMediaScanner(newPicture);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private String saveToSDCard(int resourceID, String finalName)
    {
        StringBuffer createdFile = new StringBuffer();

        Bitmap resourceImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), resourceID);       
        File externalStorageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), finalName);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        resourceImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        byte b[] = bytes.toByteArray(); 

        try 
        {
            externalStorageFile.createNewFile(); 
            OutputStream filoutputStream = new FileOutputStream(externalStorageFile); 
            filoutputStream.write(b); 
            filoutputStream.flush(); 
            filoutputStream.close();
            createdFile.append(externalStorageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

        return createdFile.toString();
    }

    private void startMediaScanner(String fileName)
    {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { fileName }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Media scan Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my original answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509877/android-dev-help-saving-an-image-from-res-raw-or-asset-folder-to-the-sd-card/4512973#4512973) I gave to you, so now it works correctly. I tried it on my phone. It resolves issue with MediaScanner you were facing with.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `MediaScannerConnection` "to refresh the folders so that the image appears in the gallery on the phone".

Comment: Hi Sorry to be a novice, but how do i do that? I have already messed around with the code above to the point that i cannot even get it to save to sd anymore, would you mind showing me the full code, i would be ever so grateful. Thankyou, Lucy

Comment: @Lucy: I haven't used `MediaScannerConnection`, but `new MediaScannerConnection(this, null).scanFile(filename, mimetype)` should index the file.

Comment: Hi, I really sorry, but you must think i'm a really stupid, i just dont know where to put your mentioned code! in the code i have already, and will it actually work with what is above?  Sorry to be a pain but this is all very new, thanks Lucy