# Downloading an audio file from raw folder to SD card

Tags: android, onclick, android-file

I need to download a file from an application. I have 5 audio files in a raw folder. On the `onclick` event of a button I need to select one audio file from 5 files and download it to an SD card.
How can I acheive this?

Comment: The same way you would save a regular audio file to the SD card. Or for that case any file.

Comment: thanks plz send a link on that plz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509877/android-dev-help-saving-an-image-from-res-raw-or-asset-folder-to-the-sd-card  this might be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

this is so simple but mistakefull ... try this code :

```
            File directoryTest = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "raw2sd");
            try {
                //coping sound file to sd
                //defining specific directory
                File soundDir = new File(directoryTest, "ORG");
                //making directories
                soundDir.mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream sound = new FileOutputStream(
                        soundDir.getPath() + "/soundName.mp3");
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.soundFile);
                int a = is.available();
                byte[] buf = new byte[a];
                is.read(buf, 0, a);
                sound.write(buf);
                sound.flush();
                sound.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
```

this is 100% tested.